# creating rotation matrices in opencv coordinate system

Tags: opencv, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have been looking at creating rotation matrices from a direction vector in the OpenCV coordinate space and there is one thing that has me slightly confused. Here is an OpenCV rotation matrix, that I got from an opencv function (let us call this matrix `r`):

```
array([[-0.4136457 , -0.19724711, 0.88881427],
       [-0.57926765, 0.810177 , -0.08978985],
       [-0.70238609, -0.55200255, -0.44938511]])
```

Now, starting from the z-axes unit vector, I am trying to recreate this vector. So, I have the following code:

```
def basis(v):
    v = v / np.linalg.norm(v)
if v[0] > 0.9:
    b1 = np.asarray([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
else:
    b1 = np.asarray([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])

b1 -= v * np.dot(b1, v)
b1 *= np.reciprocal(np.linalg.norm(b1))
b2 = np.cross(v, b1)
return b1, b2, v
```

I can call this function as:

```
x, y, z = basis(r[:, 2])
```

Then I compute the rotation matrix as:

```
avg = np.asarray([[x[0], y[0], z[0]],
[x[1], y[1], z[1]],
[x[2], y[2], z[2]]])
```

Now running this code returns:

```
array([[ 0.4582676 , 0. , 0.88881427],
[ 0.17414826, -0.98061724, -0.08978985],
[ 0.8715866 , 0.19593324, -0.44938511]])
```

So, the signs along the x and y-axes are flipped.

Now, in my basis function, if I change the line 
    `b1 = np.asarray([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])` to `b1 = np.asarray([-1.0, 0.0, 0.0])`. It returns with the correct sign like:

```
array([[-0.4582676 , 0. , 0.88881427],
[-0.17414826, 0.98061724, -0.08978985],
[-0.8715866 , -0.19593324, -0.44938511]])
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the handedness as the opencv origin is at the top left corner and the y axes is increasing in the downward direction rather than upward but the thing that has me confused is why does chaging the sign of the x coordinate of the unit vector makes a difference? I was expecting to have to change the other condition i.e. `b1 = np.asarray([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])` to have the sign flip in the y coordinate.

Comment: There is an infinite number of rotation matrices with a given z-axis. You chose one of them. Whatever created your reference matrix `r` simply chose another (either because it had more information about the underlying problem or randomly).